# Integrating a wysiwyg editor and how is communicating with the DB?

Tags: php, jquery, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg

Maybe some newbie question on this topic but I was looking at his https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ tool.

But I can't seem to find any descriptions how to integrate this? And since I don't have any experience with this kind of tools I am an bit stuck now.
Adding the JS script and extra code does not to the trick, nothing shows up.
Can someone help me out?

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar"data-target="#editor"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#editor').wysiwyg();
    });
```

Also I was wondering how is kind af data (markup and images) is stored in the DB and how to retrieve this again.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: for the rendering problem, you should have a look at the browser console to see if there is an error. this will help you solve the problem. for your 2nd question, the wysiwyg editor will post data as an html string that you can store in your database like any other string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opted for [this WISWYG editor](https://summernote.org) instead.
Much easier to install and fewer know issues.

Comment: summernote is pretty cool. I've been using it for a long time. As for your question on the saving data to the database, that form will post that textarea like any other, so you can process it in the back-end like any other field. One more thing, I think all your forms that use summernote need to have the multipart property to work properly.

Comment: It is amazing @marcogmonteiro! Any suggestions what setting to choose in the mySQL db for this kind of information?

Comment: normally in those cases I just use the type text in the database for the field that will old that information. Since you don't really know how big it will be, and unlike a normal textarea you cant really put a max-length in it to prevent big data submission.